# General piston mechanics

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking at figuring out a complex (ish) hidden door and I'm going to be using a fair few pistons. A lot of the time I'm going to need to use pistons in different orders.

Example (All sticky pistons)

**Opening**

Piston 1 pushes Piston 2 behind a block

Piston 2 pushes out a block.

**Closing**

Piston 2 pulls the block

Piston 1 pulls back Piston 2

There depending if I'm opening or closing the door I need to fire the pistons in a different order. Is there a "recommended" method of doing this in Minecraft?

Comment: The only thing you would be aware of is not to activate all pistons simultaneously. A delay between the 2nd and the 1st piston would be needed IIRC. What have you tried?

Comment: Is it a 2x2 door

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 2x2 door may I recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXAUI6hXTTQ) as it will guide you through making it. However, if you'd prefer a more 'complex' design may I recommend this [3x3 piston door tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7asFFCcoYIM). I hope this has helped as I didn't know exactly what you wanted.